# Amazon seller central API authentication

Tags: api, rest, amazonsellercentral

I am trying to pull stock quantity from amazon seller central catalog API using the product ASIN.

The issue I am facing now is with API authorization, I was expecting to send the clientId and clientSecret perhaps and retrieve the data, but the authentication process Amazon has put in place turns out to be confusing and lacks samples I could use.

I would really appreciate if anyone could share their implementation either using any of Amazon SDK (PHP or JS preferably) or just steps used in Postman.

Thanks.